# In selenium automation mouse arrow movement is it possible for a test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium .. I want to know how the mouse arrow movement can be shown to the user.I mean to say we automate certain things..  I want to know how we can get the mouse arrow movement to the user who is seeing the automation going on in selenium. Is it possible ???

Can we clearly show what is being clicked , I mean which button is being clicked by  mouse arrow movement.

I hope I am clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is add-on, which highlight elements being clicked. You can find that 1

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=element+highlighter+selenium+IDE&appver=11.0&platform=windows..

As per my knowledge it is not possible to show mouse arrow movement

Comment: Hi @rohit ware.. Thanks for the reply.. Is it possible with selenium and C# using the selenium RC to highlight the buttons or text.

Comment: really don't have any idea about C# to highlight element..above solution will work fine for selenium IDE