# Selenium View Mouse/Pointer

Tags: java, html, testing, selenium

Is there any way to actually see the selenium mouse when it's running the tests? Either with a windows cursor image or some kind of dot or cross hair or anything at all!

I'm trying to get a drag and drop function working with `selenium` and `java` in an `HTML5` web app, and being able to see the cursor to see what it's actually doing would be really useful...

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867322/in-selenium-automation-mouse-arrow-movement-is-it-possible-for-a-test-case

Comment: I found that but it didn't appear to work - I'm not sure if it's compatible with the latest version of selenium or if I have to enable it manually or something..

Comment: Also I think it's for running tests from the browser itself - I'm running them from netbeans

Comment: Hmmm.. Kindly update your post if you find a suitable answer. :)

Comment: @user2339071 I've added an answer that fixed drag and drop for me and allows the mouse to be seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I had to use the Java robot to get this working. Not only to see the mouse, but also because for an HTML5 Web App dragging and dropping is broken in selenium as two movements are needed to the drag and drop to register. Selenium only does one.

My method drags from the centre of each object and allows for an offset if you want to drag past the element you're dragging to.

```
public void dragAndDropElement(WebElement dragFrom, WebElement dragTo, int xOffset) throws Exception {
    //Setup robot
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(50);

    //Fullscreen page so selenium coordinates are same as robot coordinates
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //Get size of elements
    Dimension fromSize = dragFrom.getSize();
    Dimension toSize = dragTo.getSize();

    //Get centre distance
    int xCentreFrom = fromSize.width / 2;
    int yCentreFrom = fromSize.height / 2;
    int xCentreTo = toSize.width / 2;
    int yCentreTo = toSize.height / 2;

    //Get x and y of WebElement to drag to
    Point toLocation = dragTo.getLocation();
    Point fromLocation = dragFrom.getLocation();

    //Make Mouse coordinate centre of element and account for offset
    toLocation.x += xOffset + xCentreTo;
    toLocation.y += yCentreTo;
    fromLocation.x += xCentreFrom;
    fromLocation.y += yCentreFrom;

    //Move mouse to drag from location
    robot.mouseMove(fromLocation.x, fromLocation.y);

    //Click and drag
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    //Drag events require more than one movement to register
    //Just appearing at destination doesn't work so move halfway first
    robot.mouseMove(((toLocation.x - fromLocation.x) / 2) + fromLocation.x, ((toLocation.y - fromLocation.y) / 2) + fromLocation.y);

    //Move to final position
    robot.mouseMove(toLocation.x, toLocation.y);

    //Drop
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Comment: I'm only using robot for this drag and drop as it plain old doesn't work in selenium (see bug http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium "dragAndDrop" and "dragAndDropToObject" commands to drag and drop an element.

"mouseDown", "mouseMoveAt" and "mouseUp" commands are also very good alternatives.

**[Here is](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/search/label/dragAndDrop%20command)** very good examples of both ways in selenium IDE. You can convert that code in to java to use.

Comment: It is actually well known that HTML5 drag and drop in selenium doesn't work.. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604. I have sorted the issue and will update my question with the answer