# Try to make the mouse cursor visible in a selenium test case

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I work with Selenium Webdriver in Java on the chromedriver and I try to display the cursor permanently while a test case is performed. I have tried the robot and the action class but without any succes. for Example i tried this:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      Action action = builder.moveToElement(logo).click().build();
      action.perform();
```

In this case i can see the cursor but its not moving. Any help would be very appriciated.

Comment: Is it something like, when hovering main menu, sub menu should display??

Comment: First: thanks. Second: No i just want to have a visible mouse cursor during the whole test. so Users can see the mouse pointer movements.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd alos like to see how this is done.

Comment: Good Question @setUsername

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634050/selenium-view-mouse-pointer

Comment: I'm sorry but in that post the solution is with the Robot class. As I menitoned above, this is not working for me. I'm looking for another solution.