# Move physical mouse pointer in selenium and c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to move my physical mouse pointer. I am using selenium and c#.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(500, 500).ContextClick().Build().Perform();
//action.MoveToElement(element).ContextClick().Build().Perform();
```

Both MoveByOffset and MoveToElement are performing the right-click but the mouse pointer is not moving.

Comment: Why do you want to `move your mouse pointer` physically? Update the question with your exact _usecase_ and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: I need to show the mouse pointer moving and performing the task

Comment: But then how would you validate `mouse pointer moving` or not?

Comment: I don't need to validate mouse movements. My tests are already doing it. I just need to show the mouse movements visually.

Comment: I think it's a lot of work, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231617/try-to-make-the-mouse-cursor-visible-in-a-selenium-test-case

Comment: You can use sikuli for mouse moving even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answering From Java Perspective

**No** you can't *show the mouse pointer moving and performing the task* using the [**Actions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class.

The *Java Docs* of [**Actions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class clearly mentions that while *Automation* through *Selenium* you should use *Actions* class only for emulating complex user gestures and but not for using the **Keyboard** or **Mouse** directly.

To interact with the the **Keyboard** or **Mouse** directly i.e. to generate *native system input events* for the purposes of *Test Automation* where control of the *mouse* and *keyboard* is needed you should use the [**Robot**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) Class instead.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Why do we need Robot class when we have Actions class in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459040/why-do-we-need-robot-class-when-we-have-actions-class-in-selenium/49474596#49474596)